# Understanding assignment statement in a piece of PHP code

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a doubt on interpreting a piece of code I got from woocommerce. The code is working perfectly, BUT I have a problem understanding some part of it.

**Below is code:**

```
* Adding the Custom field to the checkout
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field');

function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

global $woocommerce;
$found = false;
//check if product already in cart

    if ( sizeof( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {

            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {               

                $_product = $values['data'];

                if ( $_product->id == 209) {

                    echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h3>'.__('My Field').'</h3>';
                    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
                        'type'          => 'checkbox',
                        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
                        'label'         => __('Fill in this field'),
                        'placeholder'   => __('Enter a number'),
                        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));

                    echo '</div>';

                  echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field2"><h3>'.__('Keywords').'</h3>';

                    woocommerce_form_field( 'enter_keywords', array(
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'required'  => true,
                    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
                    'label'         => __('Enter Keywords'),
                    'placeholder'       => __('Enter something'),
                    ), $checkout->get_value( 'keywords' ));

                    echo '</div>';
                }

            }

        }

}




/**
 * Update the order meta with field value
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta');

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ($_POST['my_field_name']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'My Field', esc_attr($_POST['my_field_name']));

        if ($_POST['keywords']) update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Keywords', esc_attr($_POST['keywords']));
}


/**
 * Add the field to order emails
 **/
add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys');

function my_custom_checkout_field_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
    $keys[] = 'My Field';
    $keys[] = 'Keywords';
    return $keys;
}



/**
 * Process the checkout
 **/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'my_custom_checkout_field_process');

function my_custom_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if (!$_POST['enter_keywords'])
         $woocommerce->add_error( __('Please enter keywords...') );
}
```

The above code is related to sending email.

**My Doubt is:**

```
Why should I give values for $keys[] as:

$keys[] = 'My Field';
$keys[] = 'Keywords';
```

Why cannot I give my_field_name , keywords as a values for `$keys[]`?

Above all these 3 functions have some understanding each other, if i give as 'My Field' and 'Keywords' for $keys[], then only iam getting an email, otherwise NOT, so why cannot give other values for $keys[] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$key` is just a variable.In the above code it just store the value in the `$key` as an array form to return as result. When you try to print that `$key` variable it should look like the below:

```
Array(
    [0] => My Field
    [1] => Keywords
)
```

**Or**

Why are you not able to change the value of `$key[]='My Field'` and `$key='Keywords'` because they are the methods(means `functions`) which is define some where in your file.If you change them ,then these function will not get executed that's why you are not be able to send the email.Try to find these functions in your files then you will have your doubt clear.

Comment: hi thansks for your quick reply! i think i didnt asked my query correctly! and I added one more function above (ie., my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta ) , all these 3 functions have some understanding each other, if i give as 'My Field' and 'Keywords' for $keys[], then only iam getting an email, otherwise NOT, so why cannot give other values for $keys[] ?

Comment: What will happen if you given a value other than `My Field`.Any error you are getting?

Comment: no error, BUT iam not receiving an email! BTW, iam using woocommerce free plugin.. if you have time, could you please download and check it.. here : http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/

Comment: @Clarsen I have updated my answer see if your doubt get clear now.

Comment: Bro, pls chk this, if you can understand http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-hooks-and-filters/  and this one too:  https://gist.github.com/1604009

Comment: BTW, i have added another function (ie., my_custom_checkout_field_process() { )  inorder to send emailing only..

Comment: With this you just override the core files and the 'My Field' is label name of field.that field should call by the ths name that why you are not able to change,if you do so please change the field label name.

Comment: What I just understood is: for $keys[] , I have to keep only those values that are given values for h3 tags (ie., <h3>'.__('My Field').'</h3>' )

 so, now what you're trying to say bro..? (iam sorry i didnt get your prev statement... ) Could u pls be bit brief?

Comment: For your understanding you just keep this as `My Field` is the name of your field label. with this you are refer that field

Comment: ok just a last query from your last reply:  'Field Label' means a value inside h3 tag? (ie., <h3>'.__('My Field').'</h3>' )

Comment: Ya it's define your field and gives the output.

Comment: Good to know it help you, the wordpress using that kind of methods it's really confusing.